# Taking multiple backups at once?

Tags: centos, backup

All the configs are located at

```
/home/achhainsan/achhainsan/glassfish/domains/blog_website/config    
/home/achhainsan/achhainsan/glassfish/domains/register_sign_in/config
```

I want to take backup of config of all these and put that into /home/achhainsan/achhainsan/all_config_bakup

Inside all_config_bakup, the config should be named blog_website_config, register_sign_in_config and so on. We can consider them a part of directory for simplicity purposes.

My attempt at solution:

- Go to `/home/achhainsan/achhainsan/glassfish/domains/`
- Do `ls`
- Store that into an array
- Loop that array
- For each **value** in the loop

  - Do `cp config /home/achhainsan/achhainsan/all_config_bakup/**$value**`
  - decrement counter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each site has a `config` and you want each of these `config` files to be named according to the site. Iterate across the sites:

```
#!/bin/sh
baseDir=/home/achhainsan/achhainsan/glassfish/domains
backupDir=/home/achhainsan/achhainsan/all_config_bakup

for siteDir in "$baseDir"/*
do
    siteName="${siteDir##*/}"    # Remove leading pathname
    cp -p "$siteDir/config" "$backupdirDir/${sitename}_config"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your making this way to complicated. If you just want he config files in 2 directories to be backed up the just use the **tar** command. If doen't look like your excluding any files.

```
cd /home/achhainsan/achhainsan/glassfish/domains/
tar -cvf config.tar blog_website/config
```

Repeat for the other directory or add them both to the same tar file.

Anther method you can try is using **git**. Git is a version control program mostly used by programmers. Some people use it to track or manage config files. Just add the files to a repo and if a files needs to be replaced then just pull it from the local git repo. For more detail look at **dotfiles** in git documentation.

Comment: There are around 7 different domains.

Comment: Ok you can have 7 different tar files or one big one. Are they all in the same directory path? (/home/achhainsan/achhainsan/glassfish/domains/) if so this is an easy fix.

Comment: yup they're in same path

Comment: So is there anything else I can help you with